# Get body of datatable as HTML element

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable that is being populated with data from ajax->mysql database. After it is populated I use various datatables tools like "rowsGroup", "searchColumns" etc to make the table look better.

Is there any way I can then get the table body as a `tbody` element with td's and tr's and append it to a variable?

My problem is that I have the datatable looking as I want it when it is initialized in javsscript (with the filters and plugins etc applied) but I have no way of exporting it like that.

My question is, how can I export it to a variable looking exactly how it is so that I can save it somewhere and re-use it elsewhere on the page or project.

===TABLE INIT===

```
let table;

    const getTableBody = async (crop) => {
      table = $('#pests_js_table').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 50,
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": {
          "url": '/assets/ajax/table_ajax_handler.php',
          "type": "POST",
          "data": {
            action: "getPestsForTable"
          }
        },
        "rowsGroup": [

        ],
        "columns": [{
            "data": "crop"
          },
          {
            "data": "weeds"
          },
          {
            "data": "chemical"
          },
          {
            "data": "product"
          },
          {
            "data": "rate"
          },
          {
            "data": "max_no"
          },
          {
            "data": "hi"
          },
          {
            "data": "mrl"
          },
          {
            "data": "pcs_no"
          },
          {
            "data": "supplier"
          },
          {
            "data": "use_by_date"
          }
        ],
        "searchCols": [{
          "search": String(crop) || null
        }],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": true
          },
          {
            "targets": [1],
            "visible": true,
            "searchable": true
          }
        ],
        "order": [
          [2, "asc"]
        ],
        "rowsGroup": [
          1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9
        ]
      });

      return table.outerHTML;
    }

    const exportPdf = async () => {
      let crops = <?=json_encode($crops)?>;
      //console.log(crops);

      // crops.map(async crop => {
      //   let tableBody = await getTableBody(crop);
      //   console.log(tableBody);
      // });

      let tableBody = await getTableBody('v7xn82Ff3XQFYwCl');
      console.log(tableBody);
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking or what your problem is.

Comment: @Wendelin I'll elaborate further, just for you

Comment: Wouldn't `let table = document.getElementById('mytable'); table.remove(); somewhereElse.append(table)` just work?

Comment: That did work, I didn't realize it would take into account the filters. Thank you

Comment: You will only get one page of data this way - the currently displayed page. Is that OK?

Comment: @andrewjames Ah no....back to square one so

Comment: I think there is a way to build the HTML which contains every row, regardless of having multiple pages (but excluding filtered rows). However, I think it may not give you exactly what you need - it may come very close. Can you clarify why you want to do this? Why (and how) do you want to re-use this HTML somewhere else on the page? This may not be the best approach to get what you want - there may be some alternatives.

Comment: @andrewjames So I have a datatable being made that uses "rowsGroup" and is filtered by a certain column and looks exactly how I want it to look. However now I need to make the same table but for each number of the filtered column. So N amount of tables formatted the desired way. My idea what to do a foreach of the values i want to filter, build the table body, append it to a variable, then go the the next element and do the same. At the end, display the variable in the DOM. It doesn't need to have datatable functionality, just the filter and grouped rows.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "each number of the filtered column"? I didn't quite follow that part. Does that mean you want each extra table to be filtered in a different way - one table per unique value in the filter column - and with the relevant filter applied to each table?

Comment: @andrewjames Yes so lets say hypothetically there is a table of countries in the world, and there is a "continent" column. I want a table for each continent and right now I have an array of continent names. But, I need to keep the table structure as it is defined in the datatables initialization. Which I will now include in the question.

So ideally, I would have 7 tables (1 per continent) with the "column defs, rowsGroup and order" attributes applied as seen above. And I would like to then add the markup for these tables into a variable to use elsewhere. (Maybe put into a pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed notes. What I have posted is not a full answer to the larger requirement you have (since that is like a mini-project, rather than a SO question) - but it helped me to understand how you might want to try to solve it. Let me know if the notes do not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a more complex requirement like the one you have, you are going to need to combine DataTables capabilities with some extra logic (JavaScript, in this case) to iterate over the set of tables you need.

So, the following example is not a complete solution - it just shows how to create one copy of your original table, with an applied filter. But this could be extended to loop over each of your continents, one-by-one.

The code creates a variable called `tableCopy` which contains a clone of the original table.  You can then use `tableCopy.outerHTML` to get the full HTML of the copied table.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

let table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  // my test data is sourced from a JavaScript variable, not from ajax:
  data: dataSet,
  // my custom code will not work if deferRender is true:
  "deferRender": false,
  // for testing, provide pre-filtered data:
  "search": {
    "search": "ni"
  },
  columns: [
    { title: "ID", data: "id" },
    { title: "Name", data: "name" },
    { title: "Office", data: "office" },
    { title: "Position", data: "position" },
    { title: "Start date", data: "start_date" },
    { title: "Extn.", data: "extn" },
    { title: "Salary", data: "salary" }
  ]

} ); 

  let tableCopy = document.getElementById("example").cloneNode(true);
  tableCopy.id = 'my_copy'; // the cloned table needs a unique ID

  //remove the (incomplete) set of <tr> nodes in the <tbody> node, since they
  // only account for the initially displayed set of rows (one page of data):
  $('tbody', tableCopy).empty();

  // we will not select any rows which have been filtered out (and are therefore hidden):
  let rowsSelector = { order: 'current', page: 'all', search: 'applied' };
  // build a complete set of <tr> nodes using the DataTables API:
  table.rows( rowsSelector ).every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
    $('tbody', tableCopy).append( this.node() );
  } );

  //console.log( tableCopy.outerHTML );

  $('#displayTarget').html( tableCopy.outerHTML );

  // redraw the main table to re-display the removed <tr> nodes:
  table.draw( false );

} );
```

In your case, you would need to extend this approach to handle multiple copies of the table.

I have not tested the following - but this shows the approach:

1. You would need an array of values to hold the copies:

   let tableCopies = [];
   contients.forEach(function (item, index) {
   tableCopies.push(document.getElementById("example").cloneNode(true));
   tableCopies[index].id = 'table_' + item; // e.g.: 'table_Europe'
   });
2. You would need to extend this section:

```
table.rows( rowsSelector ).every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
  $('tbody', tableCopy).append( this.node() );
} );
```

Instead of using the filtered data from the original table, you would loop through every row - and you would not use the `rowsSelector`:

```
table.rows().every( ... )
```

In the body of that function, you would check which continent is in the current row:

```
table.rows( rowsSelector ).every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
  let continent = this.data().continent;
  // and add the relevant continent row to the related object in the `tableCopies` array.
} );
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I have a table initialized in a function and return its outerHTML like you suggested. but if I call this function from a button, it returned null

Comment: When you do this: `table = $('#pests_js_table').DataTable({...})`, the `table` variable contains a DataTables object - not an actual HTML table. To get the `<table>` node from the DataTables object, do this: `var tableNode = table.table().node();`. And then, to get the HTML text from that node, do this: `var tableHtmlText = tableNode.outerHTML;`. These two steps should be what you need (I think).

Comment: But just to be clear: these 2 commands will only give you the visible data on the current page (assuming there are multiple pages of data in your table). It's the rest of the code in my answer that will get you everything - not just the first page. I hope that is already clear - just wanted to mention it, to be sure.

Comment: @andewjames I am trying to use `table.table().node().outerHTML` but there is no row data. It just says "Loading..."

Comment: That means there is probably a related error. Look at the console in your browser. (You typically access the browser console by hitting F12.)